# MySQL - Alternative way to extract non-exiting IDs

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I need some suggestions and ideas.

Here's the scenario. The server receives a bunch of IDs from client via Ajax. Some of these IDs may already exist in database some may not. I need to save those that are not.
One way would be to set sql queries to select * whose ID is what I have. But this requires to  a select statement for each id. Each time I receive something about 300 IDs which means 300 sql queries. This I think would slow the server. So what do you think is a better way to do this? Is there a way to extract the non-existing IDs with one SQL query?
P.S. The server is running on CakePHP.

Comment: Hard to tell without more details but `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` could be your answer.

Comment: what more details would help?

Comment: What and how are you inserting in the database?

Comment: CakePHP has this method for saving many items at once, it's a transaction basically. $this->model->saveMany($data);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is SQL's `IN` keyword:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id IN (?)
```

Where you would insert your IDs separated by comma, e.g.

```
$id_str = implode(',', $ids);
```

Make sure that $ids is an array of integers to prevent SQL injection

The outcome is a MySQL result containing all ids that exist. Build them into an array and use PHP's `array_diff` to get all IDs that do not exist. Full code:

```
$result = $connection->query('SELECT id FROM table WHERE id IN ('.
                             implode(',', $ids) . ')');
while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    $existent[] = $row[0];
}
$not_existent = array_diff($ids, $existent);
```

Comment: If you are worried about efficiency, then this solution still requires unnecessary trips to the database and PHP processing. First to check that your ids are not already in the database, then to actually insert them. INSERT IGNORE, will mean only one query and no unnecessary PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, an insert ignore could do the trick

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `table` (`id`,`col`,`col2`) VALUES ('id','val1','val2');
```

then any duplicate id's will be silently dropped, so long as `id` is unique or primary.

Also the keyword IN can be useful for finding rows with a value in a set. Eg

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN (2,4,6,7)
```